# problems to find the sold books

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to do a method to write a book's review if you have bought it, but I have a problem with my code (in customer.java -> checksold), it always appears the same notification: "You can't write a review, you haven't buy the book". A hint or some help? Thank you.

-customer.java

```
public boolean checksold(Book book){
        TypedQuery<SoldBook> query1 = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM 
        SoldBook c ", SoldBook.class);
        int index= query1.getResultList().indexOf(book);

        return index!=-1;
    }

public void review(Customer customer, Book book, String text){
       Review c= new Review();
       c.setCustomer(customer);
       c.setBook(book);
       c.setBook(book);
       book.addReview(c);
       customer.addReview(c);
       em.persist(c);
       em.merge(book);
       em.merge(customer);

}
```

-session.java

```
public boolean soldBook(){
    return customer.checksold(book);
}

public String review(){

    if (!customer.checksold(book)){
        return "IncorrectReview";
    }
    if(reviewtext.equals("") || reviewtext==null){
        return "";
    }
    customer.review(customer, book, reviewtext);
    return "CorrectReview";
}
```

Comment: Please, check this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Did you check if in fact the book is being returned on `query1.getResultList()`? Did you override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods on `Book`? `SoldBook` is a subclass of `Book`? Please complement your question with some more info.